# Magento Configurable Product Page RRP Updating

Tags: magento

We have a configurable product made up of simple products all with different prices and RRP's when on the product page you select the simple product from the drop down it updates the price however it doesnt update the RRP.

Is their a way to get the RRP to update as well as the price?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what RRP (Recommended Retail Price?) is but I think you may want to look at Magento's event system and look for the product_save_before event.

You can create an extension that will inject code just before the product saves that can modify the product. In this case you want to change the RRP.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes RRP is RRP (Recommended Retail Price?)  In terms of the product_save_before is that tied to the option drops downs generated from the simple products? I might have no mentioned but this is the front end of the site. When a users selects the simple product on the website it to change not just the sale price but the RRP as well thats shown (RRP is stored as an attribute along with the price)

Comment: I think it should tie when creating a simple product. If it does not, then it should when you save the configurable. In that case you can make the extension iterate over its children.